# Stripe ASP.NET Core Webhook always returns BadRequest

Tags: asp.net-core, stripe-payments

I am currently working on a project and integrating Stripe payment. So far I have done the Stripe Checkout Session with the prebuilt template from here - https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=checkout. This is what I have done:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> CreateCheckoutSession()
        {
            var consultation = await this.offerService.GetOnlineConsultationModelAsync();

            var options = new SessionCreateOptions
            {
                CustomerEmail = this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value,
                LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
                {
                    new SessionLineItemOptions
                    {
                        PriceData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataOptions
                        {
                            UnitAmount = (long)(consultation.Price * 100),
                            Currency = "bgn",
                            ProductData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataProductDataOptions
                            {
                                Name = consultation.Name,
                                Images = new List<string>
                                {
                                    "https://res.cloudinary.com/dpo3vbxnl/image/upload/v1641585449/pediamed/onlineConsultation_vyvebl.jpg"
                                }
                            },
                        },

                        Quantity = 1,
                    },
                },
                PaymentIntentData = new SessionPaymentIntentDataOptions
                {
                    CaptureMethod = "automatic",
                },
                PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>
                {
                    "card"
                },
                Mode = "payment",
                SuccessUrl = "http://pediamed-001-site1.btempurl.com/Checkout/SuccessfulPayment",
                CancelUrl = "http://pediamed-001-site1.btempurl.com/Checkout/CanceledPayment",
            };

            var service = new SessionService();
            try
            {
                var session = service.Create(options);
                await this.paymentService.CreateChekoutSession(session.Id, session.PaymentIntentId, session.ClientReferenceId);
                Response.Headers.Add("Location", session.Url);

                return new StatusCodeResult(303);
            }
            catch (StripeException ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(ex.StripeError.Message);

                return BadRequest(new { Message = ex.StripeError.Message });
            }
        }
```

So far so good - everything works. Then I created the template from the Fulfill your orders article - https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders. This is what I currently have:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            string secret = "whsec_......";
            var json = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            try
            {
                var stripeEvent = EventUtility.ConstructEvent(
                  json,
                  Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"],
                  secret
                );

                // Handle the checkout.session.completed event
                if (stripeEvent.Type == Events.CheckoutSessionCompleted)
                {
                    var session = stripeEvent.Data.Object as Session;

                    // Fulfill the purchase...
                    await this.FulfillOrder(session);
                }

                return Ok();
            }
            catch (StripeException ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(new {message = ex.StripeError.Message});
            }
        }
```

The problem is when I use the Stripe CLI I get this:[image]

Every time I get Bad Request, even in the details of the events in the Stripe Dashboard, but if I go to the payments dashboard they are all succeeded. Everything is done in localhost, but when deployed and using the correct api keys it is all the same. Can anyone help me with the Stripe webhook.

Comment: There are only a few statements in your `try` block that can fail. What error is your `catch` block catching? The answer is there.

Comment: @seeker I added the switch-case from here https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling?lang=dotnet , but it is the same. When I check the events, they are marked as successful, but the FulfillOrder method is adding data in my database, and nothing is added.

Comment: That's the point. The `FulfillOrder` fails and throws error, which leads to a jump into the `catch` block, from where HTTP 400 is returned. BTW, don't be confused successful payment events with webhook processing. Stripe process payment on their end and mark it as succeeded, then sends notification to your webhook endpoint and listen to your app, which returns HTTP 400. This error is logged in the other place. You can see it in the dashboard under Developers - Webhooks.

Comment: @seeker I did try commenting out the FulfillOrder method but it is the same. I did deploy the application and added the webhook in the dashboard and I get this: {
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-75747e331e813b346e49ac1a966b8aa9-fda6ed56ceff717e-00"
}

Comment: Ok, you did exclude `FulfillOrder`, thus `ConstructEvent` throws the error. Try to log this error at your end. Add `Console.WriteLine(ex.StripeError.Message);` to the `catch` block. You still need to read the error message. Maybe you got the empty json and can't construct event. You can try to check if the event was successfully constructed right after that: `Console.WriteLine("Event type: {0}", stripeEvent.Type);`

Comment: @seeker I tried and it is not logging anything. I even put a Console.WriteLine/Debug.WriteLine in the try-catch block, and nothing is written.

Comment: Well, in my stupidity I did forget to put [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] attribute and to remove the [Authorize] attribute...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might be using the signing secret from your dashboard, but when forwarding via the CLI using `listen` you need to use the CLI-specific signing secret that's provided in output when you run `listen`.

If that's not the case, can you provide more detail about the exception that's raised that leads to the bad request response path? ie, where in your code do you encounter an error?

Comment: I use the secret from the CLI, but I get the same error response. I can't find where in my code it is failing. I tried commenting out my FulfillOrder method and it still fails. I did deploy the application and in the logs I only get {
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-75747e331e813b346e49ac1a966b8aa9-fda6ed56ceff717e-00"
}